# CSOM - Download file in chunks

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, csom

I'm working on a CSOM-based PowerShell-Script to manage data in SharePoint-Online. The current challenge is to give the user some feedback regarding the download status for large files.

When uploading files, this can be done by splitting the file into segments and upload them using $File.StartUpload(), $File.ContinueUpload() and $File.FinishUpload().

For downloading on the other hand I only have the $File.OpenBinaryStream() method which will cause the full file to get downloaded at once.

Sample code:

```
$Cred = Get-Credential
$CTX = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]::new("https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/collection1/site1/")
$CTX.Credentials = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials]::new($Cred.UserName, $Cred.Password)
$CTX.Load($CTX.Web)
$CTX.ExecuteQuery()

$File = $CTX.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/collection1/site1/Ordner/Datei.zip")
$CTX.Load($File)
$CTX.ExecuteQuery()

$Stream = $File.OpenBinaryStream()
$CTX.ExecuteQuery()

#...
#Further steps to copy the $Stream.Value to a local System.IO.Stream on my harddrive
```

My script will simply freeze at the last CTX.ExecuteQuery() until the file download is done in the background. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: From a quick look at the API, there is [ExecuteQueryAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt829503(v=office.15)). This allows you to do a non-blocking call and possibly query the `Stream.Position` to determine progress? Just a guess.

Comment: The ExecuteQueryAsync() instantly freezes PowerShell because it apparently is unable to handle the returned Threading.Tasks.Task-Object. :-(

Comment: Hmm, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51218694/7571258) PowerShell is able to deal with `Task` objects.

Comment: Well in my case PS freezes when I just want to display the task object. However I may check the single properties and methods. When I run the Task.Start() method it returns an error "Start may not be called on a promise-style task."